# WPF: Reference Visibility enum value in MultiBinding Binding Source

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, visibility

I've written a general purpose prefix operator based multibinding converter that takes a list of binding values that can be either operators or values, it then computes the value based on the pre-defined behaviour of the defined set of operators.

So like this:

```
<MenuItem.Background>
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ArithmeticsConverter}">
    <Binding Source="?"/>
    <Binding Path="IsDirty"/>
    <Binding>
        <Binding.Source>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#dddf05"/>
        </Binding.Source>
    </Binding>
    <Binding>
        <Binding.Source>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#F0F0F0"/>
        </Binding.Source>
    </Binding>
</MultiBinding>
```

This returns #dddf05 if Dirty, otherwise #f0f0f0.

So this is very convenient since it's pretty much the only converter I need now, the xaml is verbose but at least I don't have to write converters for every specific case.

My problem is that I want to do something like:

?

=

null

SomeVariable

Visible

Collapsed

And set it to

```
<MyControl.Visible>
```

I.e. if SomeVariable is null, return Visible, otherwise Collapsed. But I havn't been able to reference Visibility values (or more generally, system enum values) like I am referencing color values above. I know it must be possible somehow since one can easily reference these values inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these:

```
<Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
<Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
<Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
```

The XAML processor will basically take the inner string of the tag and parse/convert it to enum value.